# Как узнать длину видео

Tags: php, xml, rest, youtube-api, rss

Как узнать длину видео Yotube  в секундах  с помощью REST запроса? Возвращает XML документ, но там нет этих данных (php)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видел,хотелось бы тут разобрать

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

При запросе `contentDetails` возвращается примерно вот это

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/MUICumcP7Lzn5pPZdAVAOhNfMIE\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/bWiFWRVFCzpSA7kbMklqZfdpS1o\"",
      "id": "Ks-_Mh1QhMc",
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT21M3S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "hd",
        "caption": "true",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "projection": "rectangular"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Можно увидеть `duration` оно в ISO 8601 формате. `PT` - period time (период времени), `M` - минуты, `S` - секунды

Comment: мне не нужны копипасты с других вопросов , я ищу нормальное решение

Comment: @VladNikitin решения для вас это полностью написанный метод? Я привел ссылку на апи YouTube, где четко описано, что возвращается и скопировал примерный результат, это не копипаст с других вопросов